# Front page is being directed to an unknown site

Tags: redirect, frontpage

Unless I type the URL of my site as example.com/wp-login.php, with URL typed as example.com, the front page is automatically directed to the following unknown site:

```
https://elementonfor.live/?utm_campaign=pEv9cTd8QNHYzqqr5UNFx2COHvnp_JE3r8uVIhm3Qww1&t=main9
```

The above website is unknown, and it is not clear where it has come from. I have scanned my website for malware. The malware plugin I am using shows the website as clean. Not sure what I should do to resolve the issue.

Comment: I'd search all of your files and your database for "elementonfor". But that does look suspicious even if your malware scanner isn't picking it up - you still may well have been hacked.

Comment: @Rup I searched all my files for ‘elementonfor’ with no match. I then searched my databases for ‘elementonfor’ and found a match in:

information_schema

PROCESSLIST

Comment: information_schema isn't part of WordPress's database. That may just have been the search job picking up itself. I guess if it's there then it's obfuscated then, which makes it sound malicious, or some odd bug? It might have meant to be "elementor.live" which is a real domain but not a genuine elementor one I don't think.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I had to contact my web host. They cleared the server cache and everything is back to normal. Thanks to @tiago-calado and @Rup for their response.

Answer (score 0):

have you installed any new plugin recently. that can be a cause.
if so try to deactivate them and check if the site still does that.
deactive all plugins not essential to home page. and check if it still does that. if so, activate one by one until you get the one is making that.

this is just one probably cause.
after you make sure any plugin is doing this. and the problem goes on. now you are sure is not a plugin.
look on your functions.php and look for any function that can be making you to be redirect.
check also if other pages load properly like exanple.com/wp-login or example.com/somepageYouKnowExistes   if this only happens on your front page can be an issue with your font-page.php, or with elementor on that page once your are being redirect to a supposed elementor page.
if any of this gives you a clue. there are many more ways to go on debuging manually.